# Meaning the word "scan and read"

Tags: word-meaning

**Scan and read that material **

This sentence is from an article "How To Improve Your Study Habits".

> I don't know the meaning **scan and read** in this sentence.
>
> I think it means **read quickly till you understand.**
>   Are there other meanings?

Answer (score 2):

Scan just means to look over something quickly. They're really just saying "look over it quickly, then read it until you understand it."